# Where is the T shortcut menu?

Tags: add-on

The old Blender had a shortcut T that displays a menu on the left side and I can't find it in newer versions (it is just rotate, scale, move options). I need it because I want to set some add-on preferences or is there another way to do it?

Comment: These options have been moved to the right hand side menu, accessible with shortcut "N"

Comment: And some of the menus are located in the Properties panel under the Screwdriver and Wrench icon.